# Javascript to select option in dropdown list with VALUE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[JSFiddle Demo of My Code](http://jsfiddle.net/sm68w/404/)

I need to change the selected OPTION in a dropdown & Also Trigger the onChange of the dropdown.

```
$('#type').val('option 1');
$('#type').val('option1');
```

I tried the above to select

```
<option value="option1">option 1</option>
```

However no luck so far!

Comment: can you explain more what you want ? here in your example not able to understand what you want  to do ?

Comment: In the JSFiddle Demo I put my code, When pressing CHANGE it is expected to update the value in the dropdown however it is currently not updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
$('#type').val('option1').change();
```

You should pass the value of the `value` attribute to the `.val()` function.

You can trigger the `change` event by calling `.change()` (with no arguments) on the jQuery object that represents the `<select>` element.

Note: Calling `.change()` with no arguments is a shortcut for calling `.trigger('change')`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbcfn7bf/)

Comment: How can I also add the following within the option: selected="selected"

Comment: Setting the value with `.val()` should cause the `<option>` with that value to have its `selected` property set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the click and use the correct ID

```
$('#change').on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();// cancel
    $('#type').val('option1').change(); // must be the value, not the text
});
```

Also you cannot submit a select. If you want, you can submit the form if it does not have a field with `name="submit"`

You will need to tell us what you want to have happen when you change the select too. for example change the select and have it submit the form it is in

```
$(function() {
  $('#change').on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();// cancel
    $('#type').val('option1').change(); // assuming you want to trigger the change 
  });
  $('#type').on('change',function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ygzm54u/)

```
<option value="option 1">option 1</option>

$('#change').click(function(){
    $('#type').val('option 1');
});
```

Comment: No, now it is identical to @Ris' solution which is not adding anything to this question either

Answer (score 0):

you can use your code like this. `#openvz` is not present in your html code that's why its not working.and you need to use `option1` instead `option 1`

```
$('#change').click(function(){
        $('#type').val('option1');
    });
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sm68w/409/)